# Errors compiling an android kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, android

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5, and I wanted to install [this kernel](https://github.com/android-linux-stable/whyred.git)

The problem is that its my first kernel compilation and I can't compile it due to some errors:

```
   CC      drivers/bluetooth/btfm_slim.o
drivers/bluetooth/btfm_slim.c:26:23: fatal error: btfm_slim.h: No such file or directory
 #include <btfm_slim.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:282: recipe for target 'drivers/bluetooth/btfm_slim.o' failed
make[2]: *** [drivers/bluetooth/btfm_slim.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:489: recipe for target 'drivers/bluetooth' failed
make[1]: *** [drivers/bluetooth] Error 2
Makefile:998: recipe for target 'drivers' failed
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
root@arnau-VirtualBox:/home/arnau/Escritorio/android/kernel# make headers_check
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

And this error:

```
 scripts/Makefile.build:489: recipe for target 'sound/soc/msm' failed
make[2]: *** [sound/soc/msm] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:489: recipe for target 'sound/soc' failed
make[1]: *** [sound/soc] Error 2
Makefile:998: recipe for target 'sound' failed
make: *** [sound] Error 2
```

How do I solve it? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in Virtualbox.

Comment: I'm not sure if the error is in kernel or Ubuntu. I think you'll get better answers on [so] or [android.se]. Moreover on googling it looks like a known issue with OnePlus also. On GitHub they suggested replacing `<>` with `""` in header file. Might work for you too.

Comment: Replacing `<>` with `""` changes the behavior. `#include <foo.h>` looks for `foo.h` in `/usr/include`, while `#include "foo.h"` looks inthe current directory (whatever that is).

Comment: Many thanks! I finally understand how to solve that errors! A greeting from Spain!

Comment: @ArnauBarbero You can consider adding what you did as an answer